# Regex find string not found in group a or not found in group b

Tags: sql, regex, coldfusion

I am trying to find cfml variables (identified by #anyvariable# ) within a SQL statement that are not already within a cfml `<cfqueryparam>` tag and also not within a cfml conditional block (identified by `<cfif></cfif>`). I've gotten as far as writing the following regexs:

#anyvariable# can be found with:  `(#[^##]+#)`

`<cfqueryparam>` content can be found with: `(?<=<cfqueryparam)(.*)(?=">)`

`<cfif></cfif>` content can be found with: `(?s)(?<=<cfif).*?(?=<\/cfif>)`

The part I am stuck on is how to unite these three regex together to end up with just the #anyvariable# results I'm looking for. In psuedo-code I want:

```
FIND (#[^##]+#) 
WHERE (#[^##]+#) NOT IN (?<=<cfqueryparam)(.*)(?=">) 
AND (#[^##]+#) NOT IN (?s)(?<=<cfif).*?(?=<\/cfif>)
```

Here's an example source string that I am searching:

`SELECT Clockin, ClockOut, LunchIn, LunchOut, TimeSheetID, Hours, isNull(RegHours,0) as RegHours, isNull(OTHours,0) as OTHours, IsNull(OT2Hours,0) as OT2Hours, IsNull(VacationHours,0) AS VacationHours, IsNull(PersonalHours,0) AS PersonalHours, IsNull(HolidayHours,0) AS HolidayHours, IsNull(SickHours,0) AS SickHours, IsNull(PremiumHours,0) AS PremiumHours, IsNull(OtherHours,0) AS OtherHours FROM TimeSheet WHERE UserID = <cfqueryparam value="#session.am_UserID#">
    AND timesheetID = #form.timesheetID# <cfif IsDefined('form.filterby') AND form.filterby IS "PayPeriod"> AND PayPeriodID = #form.PayPeriod# <cfelse> AND clockin between #Createodbcdatetime(Form.StartDate)# and #Createodbcdatetime(dateadd('h',23,Form.EndDate))# </cfif> ORDER BY clockin`

The resulting regex would find and return the match of `#form.timesheetID#`

Comment: There's two ways to go about this - one way would be to strip out all data within tags first using your second two regexes, then search the remaining code. The other would be to make use of a `negative lookahead`, as demoed here (https://regex101.com/r/cD8nG4/1) in reference to text not inside HTML tags (a similar enough use case)

Comment: I tried the following:
(#[^##]+#) (?![^<]*>|[^<>]*<\/) 
but the space in the middle makes it wierd and it still find the variable within the cfif block.

Answer (score 1):

One option might be to actively match the "bad" sequences via alternation `|`, but not "remembered" with `(?:)`, and your "good" match running last and enclosed in a capture group `()`:

```
(?:<cfif.*?\/cfif>)|(?:<cfqueryparam.*?>)|(#[^#]+#)
```

https://regex101.com/r/s3sW7N/3/